# Detecting a property checked on a check box and applying a class

Tags: jquery

I have been using the following code to update div styles when a check box is checked:

http://jsfiddle.net/tPawr/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var checkimage = $('<div class="checkbox-image" />');
    $(checkbox).each( function() {
        $(this).show().before( checkimage );
    });
    $(checkbox).prop('checked', function() {
        $('.checkbox-image').addClass('checked');
    });
    $('checkbox-image').on('click',function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('checked').after().prop('checked',$(this).is('.checked'));
    });
});
```

It was working fine, and then it stopped working and I can't work out why? Can anyone help?

Comment: what are you really trying to do?

Comment: For starters, The fiddle is using jQuery, but it is not loaded.

Comment: oops..[Fiddle Edit](http://jsfiddle.net/tPawr/6/)

Comment: maybe $(checkbox).prop works only once on page load, should be $(checkbox).on('click', function(){$(this).prop('checked') ? //do1 : //do2}), or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery library was not included in the fiddle - (In the LHS panel, first dropdown select the jQuery version)

Your `checkbox-image` selector was wrong as it missing the `.` in front.

Also the code could be simplified as

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var checkimage = $('.checkbox-image');

    checkimage.click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('checked').next().prop('checked',$(this).is('.checked'));
    }); 

    checkbox.change(function(){
        checkimage.toggleClass('checked', this.checked)
    }).change();

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4a8a6/)

Answer (score 1):

You left out a dot:

```
$('.checkbox-image').on('click',function(){
   ^
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/tPawr/7/)

Comment: doh! I must have accidentally removed it.